# IOS App fails to install after months of working correctly

Tags: ios, ipad, flash-builder, ipa

I have a bit of a problem. I've developed an app available for the iOS App store and the client wanted to add some new documents to the app. I developed this app in Flash Builder as per my employers wants. Since I have added the new documents to my app, it fails to install on any device for development testing. My provisioning profile and developer certificate are exactly the same as they were when I first built my app - they haven't expired either.

I'm literally lost as to what could be causing my App to now fail to install. Recently I found a website that recommended doing a codesign command through terminal on my .app file.

I did that and got these messages but I do not know what it is telling me:

```
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app: a sealed resource is missing or invalid
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Document d’orientation pour la soumission de matériel publicitaire.html: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Document d’orientation sur la création des trois niveaux de base.html: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Document d’orientation sur la sélection et le placement du niveau de base de l’énoncé de juste équilibre.html: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Document d’orientation sur les activités en ligne.html: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Document d’orientation sur les allégations fondées sur des études non expérimentales (observationnelles).html: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Document d’orientation sur les allégations issues d’essais de non-infériorité.html: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Document d’orientation sur l’utilisation des analyses de sous-groupes en publicité.html: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Document d’orientation sur l’utilisation des paramètres secondaires en publicité.html: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Document d’orientation sur l’utilisation des statistiques bayésiennes en publicité.html: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Document d’orientation sur l’utilisation en publicité des résultats rapportés par les patients.html: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Exemples d’énoncés de juste équilibre et de destination du lien dans Internet (publicité destinée aux professionnels de la santé).html: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/3.10 Paramètres de mesure prédéfinis.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/3.4 Paramètres de mesure prédéfinis.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/3.5 Paramètres de mesure prédéfinis.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/3.7 Paramètres de mesure prédéfinis.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/3.8 Paramètres de mesure prédéfinis.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/3.9 Paramètres de mesure prédéfinis.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Abréviations et définitions-fr-.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/figure-10-Règle coulissante.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/figure-2-Allez à la page.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle de l’analyse-2-fr.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle de l’analyse-3-fr.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle de l’analyse-4-fr.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle de l’analyse-5-fr.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle de l’analyse-6-fr.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle de l’analyse-7-fr.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle de l’analyse-8-fr.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle des allégations.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle des paramètres secondaires.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle des résultats-fr-2.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle-fr-1.1.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle-fr-1.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Table des matières.png: resource added
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Document d’orientation sur les allégations fondées sur des études non expérimentales (observationnelles).html: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Document d’orientation sur l’utilisation en publicité des résultats rapportés par les patients.html: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle-fr-1.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle de l’analyse-2-fr.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle-fr-1.1.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Document d’orientation sur l’utilisation des statistiques bayésiennes en publicité.html: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Table des matières.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle de l’analyse-7-fr.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/3.9 Paramètres de mesure prédéfinis.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Document d’orientation sur la sélection et le placement du niveau de base de l’énoncé de juste équilibre.html: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/3.10 Paramètres de mesure prédéfinis.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle de l’analyse-5-fr.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Document d’orientation sur l’utilisation des paramètres secondaires en publicité.html: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Document d’orientation sur les allégations issues d’essais de non-infériorité.html: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Document d’orientation sur la création des trois niveaux de base.html: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/figure-10-Règle coulissante.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle de l’analyse-3-fr.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/3.5 Paramètres de mesure prédéfinis.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Exemples d’énoncés de juste équilibre et de destination du lien dans Internet (publicité destinée aux professionnels de la santé).html: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle de l’analyse-8-fr.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle des allégations.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/3.8 Paramètres de mesure prédéfinis.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/figure-2-Allez à la page.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Document d’orientation pour la soumission de matériel publicitaire.html: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Document d’orientation sur les activités en ligne.html: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle des résultats-fr-2.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle de l’analyse-6-fr.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/guidelines/Document d’orientation sur l’utilisation des analyses de sous-groupes en publicité.html: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle des paramètres secondaires.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/3.4 Paramètres de mesure prédéfinis.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Abréviations et définitions-fr-.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/Liste de contrôle de l’analyse-4-fr.png: resource missing
/Users/mcorway/Desktop/Payload/PAABCodeApp.app/www/img/3.7 Paramètres de mesure prédéfinis.png: resource missing
```

My app loads a lot of files, it's basically a reader that allows the viewer to read documents and mark them up with highlights etc, so it requires a lot of resource files.

Again, I've never had this problem until my latest update. My IPA renders out fine every time, it just fails to install.

My developer certificate does expire in 15 days, but I figure that shouldn't be an issue until it has actually expired.

Does anyone have any idea what could be my problem? Or what this error dump means?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the new files and see if the app still won't install.

If it doesn't I would suggest revoking your iOS certificates and provisioning profiles and starting them afresh.

Comment: Yes, good advice as I tried this and it still would not install anymore. I then went into terminal and did a codesign -dvvv on the app file to find that it was somehow including my Distribution certificate NOT my Developer certificate. Thinking I had solved my problems, I deleted every reference and trace of the Distribution certificate on my Mac. I recompiled and checked with -dvvv again to see that yes! my Iphone Developer certificate was being included. Alas, failure again - still won't install. I'm at a loss. I have no idea what to do now. I'll try revoking my cert now...